Short anime showcase series on french television during the 90's
When I was still in high-school, sometimes during the 90's when the internet was not yet in everyone's home, I used to get all my information and movies from the TV. We had cable that brought us West European and American TV and movies and music. That is how I discovered Anime through French and German TV channels.
On one of the French channels (I think Tele5/France5) there was a short info show that was presenting clips (at least 5) from various Japanese Animes. It was aired at least twice a day and it was episodic. I can't remember the name of the show, it would start and end quickly as a commercial segment that only showcased Anime. The Animes that I saw back then really appeal to me. I love 80's and 90's Anime, but I can't find any of the ones I use to see in that show. I need a name, a video - something that I could track.
Some of the clips I remember:
A boy is chased by a gang atop of a skyscraper. He holds a crystal ball that he drops and then jumps in a black hole.
A female pilot lands a spaceship shaped as a woman in something as a web structure and it causes her pain. There seems to be other ships caught in the web.
Two giant robots fight on a metal structure like an unfinished building and destroy it in the process.
A swimsuit contest with long legged beauties and something going on in the background (but who cares about that, really? hehe)
I don't remember any French Animes, but I did spent many late hours watching Anime in German (Vox). They were having marathons. Not good... First saw Evangelion there. Had school the next morning.
